# Can't open smartgit, Java error

Tags: software-installation, java, openjdk, jdk

I've installed smartgit via ppa and tried to open it via GUI and it didn't. I tried to run `smartgit` command in terminal and it gave me this:

```
Ignoring following line in file /usr/share/smartgit/bin/smartgit.vmoptions
jre=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/
Ignoring following line in file /home/yarkin/.smartgit/smartgit.vmoptions
jre=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/
If you experience strange GUI bugs or crashes, try setting GTK_THEME=Adwaita.
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/syntevo/QBootLoader has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:601)
```

I don't know what else i should provide, please let me know so that i can update question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the PPA. Simply grab the software from the developer's website.

https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/

I always use the "Download for Linux" version. Just unpack it, and you can run the `.sh` file directly. There is also a convenient `add-menuitem.sh` script in the `/bin` folder, that creates shortcuts for Smartgit, so you can start it from your desktop environment's launcher.

Just move the unpacked folder first to somewhere where you won't lose it. Like `~/Documents` probably is a safe place.